# Padding increasing width of a border-box

Tags: html, css

According to the [W3C spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#valdef-box-sizing-border-box), `box-sizing: border-box` should draw padding inside the width/height. This means `padding` should not increase the width of that element.

However, I'm encountering an odd case where padding **is** in fact increasing the width, after a mysterious threshold:

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
}
input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
}
#a {
  padding-right: 84px;
}
#b {
  padding-right: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>No padding</span>
  <input />
  <input />
  <span>Foo bar this determines the space</span>
</div>
<hr>
<div>
  <span>84px of padding</span>
  <input />
  <input id="a" />
  <span>Foo bar this determines the space</span>
</div>
<hr>
<div>
  <span>100px; width expands ?!?!</span>
  <input />
  <input id="b" />
  <span>Foo bar this determines the space</span>
</div>
```

Click run code snippet and **scroll down to see the issue**. The width of the `<input>`s should be 214px, but setting more than 84px of padding starts increasing the width. Why is this happening, and how can I prevent it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> This means `padding` should not increase the width of that element.

Not completely true. If after subtracting the padding from the outer width, the remaining inner width is negative, it will be clamped at zero, because it can't be negative.

Therefore, yes, adding padding can increase the outer width of a box.

However, your case is interesting because the increment of outer width happens before it might be expected.

What happens is that there is an inline-block container with `width: auto`. That means its width will be the [shrink-to-fit](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#shrink-to-fit-float)/[fit-content](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-sizing-3/#fit-content-size) size. That is,

> min([max-content size](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-sizing-3/#max-content), max([min-content size](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-sizing-3/#min-content), [fill-available
>   size](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-sizing-3/#fill-available-size)))

Therefore, its width depends on the width contributions of the content.

Then there is an input width `width: 100%` inside that inline-block.

That percentage should be resolved relatively to the width of the containing block (the inline-block), but that's a circular definition!

Therefore, the width is not definite. In that case [CSS Sizing](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-sizing-3/#replaced-intrinsic) says

> For replaced elements, the [min-content](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-sizing-3/#min-content) size and [max-content](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-sizing-3/#max-content)
>   size are equivalent and correspond to the appropriate dimension of the
>   concrete object size returned by the [default sizing algorithm](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-images/#default-sizing)
>   [CSS3-IMAGES] of the element, calculated with an unconstrained
>   specified size.

That algorithm returns the [intrinsic width](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-images/#intrinsic-width) of the replaced element.

> The [min-content contribution](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-images/#default-sizing) and [max-content contribution](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-images/#intrinsic-width) in
>   each axis is the element’s specified outer size in that axis, if
>   definite; otherwise, they are the [min-content size](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-sizing-3/#min-content), as specified
>   above, plus the element’s margin/border/padding in that axis [...].

That is, the width of the inline-block will be, at least, the intrinsic width of the input plus its padding.

Once that width is known, the percentage of the input can be resolved.

Then, let's say

- The text with has width `x`
- The input has intrinsic width `y`
- The input has padding of width `z`

Assuming there is enough available space, the width of the inline-block (and the input) will be `max(x, y+z)`.

Therefore, increasing the padding `z` won't affect the resulting width if `x >= y+z`. But once you reach `x == y+z`, the resulting width will be increased with padding.

You can avoid this behavior by using a definite width instead of a percentage, and using `min-width` to achieve the desired percentage width.

```css
input {
  width: 0; /* Ignore intrinsic width */
  min-width: 100%; /* Instead of width */
}
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
}
input {
  display: block;
  width: 0; /* Ignore intrinsic width */
  min-width: 100%; /* Instead of width */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
}
#a {
  padding-right: 84px;
}
#b {
  padding-right: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>No padding</span>
  <input />
  <input />
  <span>Foo bar this determines the space</span>
</div>
<hr>
<div>
  <span>84px of padding</span>
  <input />
  <input id="a" />
  <span>Foo bar this determines the space</span>
</div>
<hr>
<div>
  <span>100px; width expands ?!?!</span>
  <input />
  <input id="b" />
  <span>Foo bar this determines the space</span>
</div>
```

Comment: This isn't being hit here. 214 - 84 = 130, the inner width should still be positive

Comment: @gladsocc Uhm, I see, it seems due to the intrinsic width of replaced elements. Let me check the spec.

Comment: Very interesting; this is the first time I've heard about intrinsic width. Thank you for your amazing research.

Comment: @gladsocc See the edit, I explained with full details.

Comment: Really nice, detailed explanation.